# Django translation outside the browser session

Tags: django

Django in a browser session translates everything fine from one language to another according to the users' browser settings or the language they chose in their profile.
Now when sending a mail to a user (let's say when another user leaves a comment on some content and Django automatically sends an email to the owner of the content to alert her) I don't understand how Django knows what language to use since there is no session to look at. What is the correct way to handle that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was given the answer on the Django users Group by Tom Evans: 
the tool is

```
from django.utils import translation
```

then it can be used in this scenario:

```
cur_language = translation.get_language()
translation.activate(get_lang_for_user(user))
# send email, tweet, etc
translation.activate(cur_language)
```

and the docs are here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#using-translations-outside-views-and-templates